# how to doc 'requestParameters' as array

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I have a service with JSON **array** payload like:

```
[{ message: "one"}, {message: "two"}]
```

How can I document this using `spring-restdocs`?

```
MessageContract contractOne = new MessageContract();
contractOne.setMessage("one");

List list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(contractOne);

this.webTestClient
                .post().uri("/messages")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(list))
                .exchange().expectStatus().isCreated().expectBody()
                .consumeWith(document("POST messages",
                        requestParameters(
                                parameterWithName("message").description("Massage we should save"),
                        ))
                );
```

I got an error:

```
org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.SnippetException:
Request parameters with the following names were not found in the request:
[message, ...]
```

I think that restdocs does not see field **because its insede an array**. How to handle it correctly?

**Added:**

Resource:

```
@PostMapping
private Mono<ResponseEntity> postMessage(@RequestBody List<MessageContract> contract) {
    return service
            .save(contract)
            .collectList()
            .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.CREATED));
}
```

Comment: Can you share your endpoint implementation and the list creation code?

Comment: @CristianColorado done

Comment: If you want to document the body of a request, you should use `PayloadDocumentation.requestFields`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a little test for you to show the array documentation with `requestFields.fieldWithPath`.

Please verify, that this approach is working for you.

```
    @Test
    public void documentRequestBodyArray() {
        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/contract")
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .syncBody(List.of(new MessageContract("one"), new MessageContract("two")))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectBody()
                .consumeWith(document("documentArray",
                        requestFields(
                                fieldWithPath("[]").description("a message array"),
                                fieldWithPath("[].message").description("a message"))));
    }
```

The `MessageContract` here looks like:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageContract {
    private String message;
}
```